# Prove that $\alpha + \beta = \sup E$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$,$B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are nonempty and bounded above. By axiom of completeness, we know $\alpha = \sup A$ and $\beta = \sup B$ exists.

Let $$E = \{x+y \text{ such that }x \in A \text{ and } y \in B\}$$

Prove that $\alpha + \beta = \sup E$

Comment: I reordered the sentences and typeset the question. For some basic information about writing math on this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it.  I've been wondering where to get some info on how to format questions.

Answer (score 2):

$1$. First show that $\alpha + \beta$ is an upper bound. This should be straightforward.

$2$. Next argue out why $\alpha + \beta$ should be the least upper bound i.e. consider $\alpha + \beta - \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and argue out why it cannot be an upper bound by producing elements $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ such that $$x+y > \alpha + \beta - \epsilon$$

Comment: Could you consider some arbitrary upper bound of E, and call it me.  This, for any e in E, e<=m.  So for any x in A and y in B, x+y <= m.  But since x and y are arbitrary and you already proved alpha + beta is an upper bound, alpha + beta <= m.  Thus, alpha + beta = supE.

Is this correct?