# Proving $\sup(A)+\sup(B)=\sup(A+B)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A, B$ be two nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are bounded above. Define $$A+B=\{a+b \;|\; a\in A, b\in B\}$$

I know there is a method using two inequalities
$$\sup(A)+\sup(B)\le\sup(A+B)$$
$$\sup(A)+\sup(B)\ge\sup(A+B)$$

But someone asked me if following method is okay or not.

> Let $\sup(A)=\alpha$, and let $\sup(B)=\beta$.
>
> (i) Then for all $a\in A$, $a\le\alpha$ and for all $x\in A$ which is less than $\alpha$, there exists $a\in A$ such that $x<a$, repectively with $b\in B$ and for some $y$ and $\beta$.
>
> (ii) So for all $a+b\in A+B$, $a+b\le\alpha+\beta$ and for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x+y<\alpha+\beta$ there exists $a+b\in A+B$ such that $x+y<a+b$.
>
> (iii) Which implies $\sup(A+B)=\alpha+\beta=\sup(A)+\sup(B)$.

Is it good? I think if there is a problem that it will be the (ii).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\alpha + \beta = \sup E$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296738/prove-that-alpha-beta-sup-e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that (ii) is not completely correct. Let $C := A + B$. As you show in the first sentence of (ii), the set $C$ is bounded from above by $\alpha + \beta$ and it is clearly nonempty. So, there exists the supremum $s := \sup C$. What is also correctly shown is that $s \leq \alpha + \beta$.

I don't like the fact that you decompose the left hand side in the inequality $x + y < \alpha + \beta$.

Here is how I would do it: Let $z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $z < \alpha + \beta$. Then you know that there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $z + \varepsilon = \alpha + \beta$. Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are suprema, you know that there exist $a \in A,b \in B$ such that
$$
\alpha - \varepsilon / 2 < a \leq \alpha
$$
and
$$
\beta - \varepsilon / 2 < b \leq \beta.
$$

From this we get that
$$
z = \alpha + \beta - \varepsilon = \alpha - \varepsilon/2 + \beta - \varepsilon/2 < a + b \leq \alpha + \beta,
$$
i.e. we have found $a + b \in A + B$ such that
$$ z < a + b.$$