Proof that $\sup(A+B)=\sup(A)+\sup(B)$ in $\mathbb{R}$
Prove that $\sup(A+B)=\sup(A)+\sup(B)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, where $$A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$$
This is not a duplicate since it's a different approach.
Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ and bounded above.
Since $a<\sup(A)$ and $b<\sup(B)$. We know that $\sup(A)+\sup(B)$ is an upper bound of $A+B$.
Let's assume that there exists an $m\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a+b<m<\sup(A)+\sup(B)$.  Then we have the sets $A+B$ and $\{m\}$ with $a+b<m$ but then since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete there exists a $r\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a+b< r<m$ which contradicts that m is $\sup(A+B)$.
Is the step using the completeness really justified?
Edit: I think it's not since then I could argue that we could find an $k\in \mathbb{R}$with $a<k<\sup(A)$ using this argument.

@abc1455 This should be a $m$

$a<\sup(A)$ (assuming you mean $\forall a\in A,\ a<\sup (A)$) may not be true.

We have $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. $A+B={a+b\mid a\in A,b\in B$

You are the one who wants to be read.

Why the strict inequality? Isn't equality viable for a supremum

First, if $m=sup(A+B)$ then $a+b\leq m$ not a strict inequality. Second, your quantifiers are not clear when you say $a+b<r<m$ Do you mean there is one $r$ that works $\forall a\in A ,b\in B$ or did you mean $\forall a,b$ you can find an $r$ for these specific $a$ and $b$?.

@SassatelliGiulio Sorry you are right they aren't strict.

Completeness, in the sense of orders, has nothing to do with the property $[\forall x,\forall y,(x<y\rightarrow \exists z, x<z<y)]$. ${0,1}$ with the usual order is complete, but lacks this property; $\Bbb Q$ has this property but isn't complete; $\Bbb R$ has both; $\Bbb Z\cup ((0,1)\cap \Bbb Q)$ has neither.

@abc1455 It's $\forall a,b$ and I think the idea in this post doesn't work at all.

@SassatelliGiulio Thank you. Yes this idea is flawed

@Riemann Yes you are right. Are you from MIT? I saw Cambridge MA in your profile

@ Arthr No, but MIT is my dream university!

@Riemann Good luck. Maybe you will be there in future

The better answer to this question is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296738/prove-that-alpha-beta-sup-e
